# Unable to access one javascript file from another javascript file's class

Tags: javascript, class

I have one javascript file called idb.js ([IndexedDb Promised API](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb)). Which looks something like this:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
 //huge code goes here
}());
```

I want to use this idb file inside another javascript file called dbhelper.js

```
class DbHelper {
 let idbPromise = idb.open(); //accessing idb.open function of idb.js file

//rest of the code

}
```

I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error at `idb.open()` function. Also, I have already checked whether that open() function has any extra or missing characters like `{ or ( or ;`. But there is no error in syntax. I did copy paste the same code in another javascript file, without defining any class and it's working fine.

Comment: did you import that first file into the second file?

Comment: @DananjayaAriyasena I'm loading first file before second file in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using invalid syntax. Try simplifying your code to see what you're doing wrong. Even just this will give you the same error:

```
class A {
  let b = 1;
}
```